# How to write data from cheerio to a file

Tags: fs, cheerio

I am scraping a directory of files with cheerio and need all this data to end up in one .json file.

I can get all my data to console fine. I see everything I need and when I try to write it to file I end up with nothing, or one file. I've tried async/await, promises, fs.writeFile, and fs.createFileStream. I'm very confused at the moment.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { findContent } = require('./getItems.js');


const glob = require('glob');

glob('./public' + '/**/*.html', {}, (err, htmlFiles) => {
        if (err) return console.error('handle err', err);
        htmlFiles.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    var items = [];
                    var $ = cheerio.load(data)
                    const result = findContent($, true);

                    console.log(result);

                    items.push(JSON.stringify(result))
                    console.log(items.toString());

                }
            })

        })
    });
```

This consoles everything I need.

I can't figure out how to write my data

```
writeStream.write(items,'UTF8');
```

I get chunk error messages, or items is not defined, ...

Comment: You need to do it in another callback or await everything. I would get rid of whatever filehound is if I were you, you will get better help here if you don't use obscure dependencies

Comment: I won't always know how many files there are in a folder and filehound finds all of them. It works well for finding files. I'll replace it with glob though if it lets people help. From what I have I can console all my data from all my files. I don't know how to get it all to write into a single json file. I think fs.createWriteStream is good? But then I get chunk error messages. When Iv'e tried to await the writeStream my data is undefined.  I've tried fs.writeFileSync, but it overwrites with each .html doc.

Comment: Where is the code where you try to write your data? You have only posted `writeStream.write(items,'UTF8'); `. Could you add the rest of the code?

Comment: I am stuck on where to write my data.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're adding those in a callback. Try it like this:

```
let items = [];
let $
let data
let result

;(async function(){
  let files = await glob(...)
  for(var file of files){
    data = fs.readFileSync(file)
    $ = cheerio.load(data)
    result = findContent($, true);
    console.log(result);
    items.push(result)
  }  
  fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(items))
})()
```

Comment: This gives me the error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: files is not iterable"

Comment: That was just a suggestion of how to do it and avoid callbacks. You're obviously going to need to adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this seems to be working now.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { findContent } = require('./getItems.js');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.json', 'utf8');
const FileHound = require('filehound');



const files = FileHound.create()
    .paths('./public')
    .ext('html')
    .find((err, htmlFiles) => {
        if (err) return console.error('handle err', err);
        htmlFiles.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              } else {
                var items = [];
                var $ = cheerio.load(data)
                const result = findContent($, true);
                items.push(result)
                writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(items));
              }
            })
          })
        })
```

and with glob

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { findContent } = require('./getItems.js');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.json', 'UTF8');

const glob = require('glob');

glob('./public' + '/**/*.html', {}, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error finding files')
  } else {
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          var items = [];
          var $ = cheerio.load(data)
          const result = findContent($, true);
          items.push(result)
          writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(items));
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```